# Compound verb and present participle

Tags: verbs, present-participles

> She cooked and is preparing the dinner (She is still preparing it now)

Is it correct? I can't find the term for the structure, what is the name of such sentence? I found about compound verbs, but it shows double verbs for single subject and is not for present participle, could someone please explain to me the official rules? Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear but this doesn't look to me like a compound verb. The construction "is preparing" uses *is* as an **auxiliary verb** to convey the present progressive tense.

Your sentence sounds odd to me though. Often preparing the dinner means doing the washing, chopping, etc. that has to be done *before* cooking. Maybe you mean that she has finished cooking and is now **plating up** the dinner. Then you would write:

> She has cooked the dinner and is now plating it up.

One final point: "Thanks before" should be "Thanks in advance".

Comment: thanks for the answer , yes I knew about that, but I was looking for the rules, what is the structure called for present participle after conjunction and clause, I hope you can help me, I am beginner in English.

Comment: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/compoundverb.htm

Comment: I looked on that site about compound verb, it's for one subject that has more than one verb, but it doesn't explain if the second verb is in progressive structure, could you provide me the rules for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: That website has a very strange definition of compound verb. Usually a compound verb is something like "stir-fry", or "force-feed", where two verbs are compounded into one.

Comment: What you are talking about is just a subject with a list of verbs after it (for example, "I like cooking, watching TV and eating ice cream"), but that's not what you have in your example.

Comment: Anyway, I found this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10970/verbs-in-a-list-separated-by-commas that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear enough, I asked for the name of the sentence of having single subject with a verb and a progressive after conjunction without needing to repetitively put the subject twice.

Comment: It's like, she has done the work and (progressive that linked to the main subject) is now watching TV.